# How to use each function, this from jquery to Dart Language?

Tags: dart, dart-webui, dart-editor, dart-js-interop

I have a function in jquery  as below

```js
function findMax(){
 $( ".elements" ).each(function( ) {
  if($(this).css('z-index')>max1)
  max1=$(this).css('z-index');
  max1=parseInt(max1);
 });
}
```

I have to implement this function in Dart Language. Facing problems with syntaxes in using .each function and 'this' function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The equivalent of jQuery :

```js
$(".elements").each(function( ) {
  // do something with this being one of elements with a 'elements' class
  // you can access the current element with $(this)
});
```

is in Dart :

```dart
querySelectorAll('.elements').forEach((Element e) {
  // do something with e being one of elements with a 'elements' class
  // you can access the current element with e
});
```

Comment: It should be noted that `e` can also be the direct implementation of any HTML element like InputElement, SpanElement, DivElement... I preferr this since it make it obvious what element I am dealing with

Comment: Do you mean to use e instead of this in this format **e.style.background**??

Comment: Yes. When you use JQuery `each` `this` points on the current element and `$(this)` gives a jQuery wrapper around `this`. In Dart, you don't have such wrapper but the API of `Element` is really straightforward and powerfull.